# R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version error

Tags: java, android

```
public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int 1322882=0x7f020000;
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020001;
        public static final int tab_icon1=0x7f020002;
        public static final int tab_icon2=0x7f020003;
        public static final int w1=0x7f020004;
        public static final int w2=0x7f020005;
    }
```

I am getting error on this line 
            `public static final int 1322882=0x7f020000;`. I do not know how to solve this. I have cleaned the project, rebuild it but still did not find solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can not set `Resource` name as `number`. Check your `Resource` folder if you have name any `image` or `drawable` name as `1322882`.

`Number` is not allow as `first char` of `resource` also `not allowed capital letter`.

Answer (score 1):

Variable name can't be a `int`. Add at least one literal character and it will be okay then.